# How to create a complex shadow in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently redesigning a poorly written website to remove images and convert them to `CSS` as much as possible, among other tasks. I have come up on one particularly difficult graphic (there are 3 of these, one for each tab that is active):

[image]

Note how the shadow goes around the edges of the tab handle and stays above the other two tab handles. I've tried everything I could think of to get this shadow right with `CSS`, but I don't seem to be getting anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: Post the CSS and HTML you have so far, we need a minimum reproducible example to answer your question effectively

Comment: I didn't really have much to show, even after two hours of trying, so sorry about that. I also don't get the "too broad" thing, I really can't think of a way to make the question more specific. This is due to my lack of knowledge, sure, but I did spend a lot of time trying and failing so I really had no other way. Sorry about that too.

Comment: @Arshia001, I agree with you that it's not a case of "too broad" question, since it's very specific about what's being desired. The problem is that many guys here don't like when the question has no code, so the next time show at least some HTML and CSS of your better result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the real problem isn't only the active tab overlaping the others with shadows, what could be easily achived with simple `z-index` and `box-shadow` tricks.

The desired *rounded out* effect needs more advanced tricks, not being possible directly with `border-radius`. The trick I prefer uses gradients, based on [Lea Verou's negative border radius with gradients](http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/beveled-corners-negative-border-radius-with-css3-gradients/), since it can be used along with shadows almost perfectly.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.nav a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $('.nav li').removeClass('active')
    var h = $(this).attr('href')
    $(this).parent().addClass('active')
    $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active')
    $(h).addClass('active')
  })
})
```

```css
html {
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 20px 10px auto;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
}
.nav {
  /* Using flex to easyly adjust to any number of tabs */
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 -10px;
}
.nav li {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  list-style: none outside none;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
.nav .active {
  z-index: 2;
  background: #fff;
}
.nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 40px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #777;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
.nav .active a {
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 0;
  color: #111;
  padding: 10px 40px 11px;
  box-shadow: -3px -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05), 3px -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
.nav .active:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
}
.nav .active:first-child a {
  border-left: 0;
}
.nav .active:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
}
.nav .active:last-child a {
  border-right: 0;
}
.nav .active:not(:first-child) a:before,
.nav .active:not(:last-child) a:after {
  /* Rounded out corners are just generated elements */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  bottom: 9px;
}
.nav .active:not(:first-child) a:before {
  /* The left rounded out tab are achived here. */
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, transparent 8px, #aaa 9px, #fff 10px);
  left: -9px;
}
.nav .active:not(:last-child) a:after {
  /* The right rounded out tab are achived here. */
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0, transparent 8px, #aaa 9px, #fff 10px);
  right: -9px;
}
.tab-content {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 6px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  background: #fff;
  color: #111;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.tab-pane {
  display: none;
}
.tab-pane.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">1</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">2</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">3</div>
</div>
```

Of course, JavaScript was used only to handle the tab change, to better show the differences on each tab position styling.

Comment: Oh my god, I didn't really think it was possible at all! Thanks a lot, I'll have to thoroughly study your code.